# iPad mimic facebook single navigation bar with multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, facebook, ipad, uinavigationbar

For an iPad app I'm developping, I would need a splitview controller like most iPad apps but with a small difference : the app needs to have a single `UINavigationBar` at the top.

The facebook app seems to do exactly what I need :

[image]

Is this using a custom [Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) ? Or is there another workaround?